# Create a triangular mesh using Delaunay methods

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, triangulation, delaunay

I'm trying create a triangular mesh using python.
As I know the boundary points, I think the delaunay method is more appropriated.
I tried use scipy. the code is very simple

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
pixelpoints = np.transpose(np.nonzero(binaryImage))
tri = Delaunay(pixelpoints)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.triplot(pixelpoints[:,0], pixelpoints[:,1], tri.simplices.copy())
plt.plot(pixelpoints[:,0], pixelpoints[:,1], 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output triangulation]
But I don't want this. I'd like to mesh inside the image bounds. Also, I don't want to mesh inside the holes.
Can I control the number of triangles to cover a surface?
Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove additional triangles using the `Polygon.IsPointInside(tCentroid)` where `tCentroid` is the triangle centroid. `IsPointInside()` can be derived by this: http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html.

Answer (score 0):

The [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) program supports both these needs: refining triangles to a prescribed size and removing triangles outside the polygon or in holes. There seems to be a [python interface](https://pypi.org/project/triangle/) floating around: the [API](https://rufat.be/triangle/API.html) describes how to specify holes and a maximum triangle area.